# Main character is reincarnated and submits future mecha plans to the AI in charge of world

Tags: story-identification, manga

The main character is reincarnated and submits future mecha plans to the AI in charge of world. She reincarnates into the past and submits Mecha plans to the AI that runs everything in the world. I think its name is justice, although I could be wrong though. There are aliens. I remember one chapter where there was this one guy out in space, she was a teacher, and practically had a harem of girls with him and in the future he was going to bomb the Earth but the MC knew exactly where he was since he's from the future and was able to stop him and get something from him.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Can you please [edit] this to add punctuation?  The way your sentences run into one another, I can't figure out how it should be read.  Also, where and when did you read this?

Comment: @NONE NONE - You use pronouns like "he" and "she" a lot in this description, but I can't always tell who you're referring to in each instance. Please try and be clearer about who you're referring to with these pronouns. It would also be helpful to know if this was in full colour or mostly black & white.

Comment: Is she a robot after "reincarnating", or still a human?